# How to Liquibase maven plugin integratie with specified schema in MS Server

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

That is my configuration of liquibase maven plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>status</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db-changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
      <driver>${liquibase.driver}</driver>
      <username>${liquibase.username}</username>
      <password>${liquibase.password}</password>
      <url>${liquibase.url}</url>
      <referenceDriver>${liquibase.driver}</referenceDriver>
      <referenceUsername>${liquibase.username}</referenceUsername>
      <referencePassword>${liquibase.password}</referencePassword>
      <referenceUrl>${liquibase.url}</referenceUrl>
      <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

In case I'm using

```
<profile>
  <id>local</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <liquibase.url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433</liquibase.url>
    <liquibase.driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</liquibase.driver>
    <liquibase.username>SA</liquibase.username>
    <liquibase.password>dev-pa$Sw0rd</liquibase.password>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

it works fine. But if i try to use:

```
    <liquibase.url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=eBatch_Retry</liquibase.url>
```

it gives me exception.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.3:migrate (default-cli) on project dc-database: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "eBatch_Retry" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:0a136358-788a-4b78-b779-76175467a832 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

schema was created using script:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'eBatch_Retry')) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [eBatch_Retry]')
END
```

User that i'm using granted to everything in the db. It seems like permission issue and I very confused because of it.

Is any ideas how to manage my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to create database because of schema has different meaning. After applying next instruction my liquibase managed default schema inside of it (dbo).

```
CREATE DATABASE eBatch_Retry;
```

for case:

```
<liquibase.url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=eBatch_Retry</liquibase.url>
```

Comment: To be fair and IMHO, the MsSqlServer "usage" of schema seems more like the correct overall RDBMS use of "schema".     If you've worked with several RDBMS's, this Oracle comment is a tell-tale.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6014.htm.  "This statement does not actually create a schema."    << Ha ha.  The "Create Schema" command in Oracle (and its kissing cousin MySql) ... "This statement does not actually create a schema."